# Does the Smooth Streaming 2.0 installation work on Windows 7 RC?

Tags: iis-7

I downloaded the Smooth Streaming 2.0 release via the Web Platform Installer http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

After I got it all set up and downloaded the sample content. I found that it would not stream the videos. The page loaded fine, but it would only show me a static frame of video. I could seek around in the Silverlight player and it would refresh, but the framerate would not go above Zero.

Anyone else seeing that issue on Win 7 RC in IIS 7.  Is this supported on Win 7 RC? 
Just wondering, cause it would be nice to have this running on my development box for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! 
I removed the IIS Media 2.0 release after the Web Platform installed it and installed the latest IIS Media 3.0 beta that was published in the Web Platform installer.

Then it started working just fine.

Standalone installer for 3.0 is here also.
http://www.iis.net/extensions/LiveSmoothStreaming

Now I am having issues with the manifest that was created by Expresion Encoder 3, but that is a different question.